# Edit SOAP Response Tags using Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I'm writing a Java web service using Axis2, this is my SOAP response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:MyMethodResponse xmlns:ns="http://mynamespace">
            <ns:return>
               ...
            </ns:return>
        </ns:MyMethodResponse>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I edit this response?

I need to change the tag "ns:return" into "MyMethodResult" and "soapenv" prefix into "soap" because of backward compatibility to the old client. I cannot use JAX-WS annotations. Thanx